# structuring an api endpoint

Tags: c#, api-design, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an endpoint like the following to get resource by id:

```
/api/ticket/{id}
```

Now I want to list tickets by user id. I thought of the following:

```
/api/ticket/user/{userId}
```

But I just feel the above doesn't sound ok. I could use the following, but again it makes `userId` optional, which is not an intention.

```
/api/ticket?userId=x
```

Another option I can think of is,

```
/api/user/{userId}/ticket
```

But again, I just feel the above is taking the resources out of my `/api/ticket` service, and appear disguising in the eyes of consumers and api maintainers.

How do you people go about this?

Comment: How about `/api/ticket/list?userId=x` that way you could also provide other "filters" on the same endpoint and have it clear you are listing tickets.

Comment: BTW: `/api/user/{userId}/ticket` I as an api consumer, I would expect _not_ to get a list of tickets because of the singular form. If this shall be clear to be returning a list of tickets, I'd make it `tickets`.